# Create aggregated user stats with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, database

I am building a MongoDB database that will work with an Android app. I have a user collection and a records collection. The records documents consist of GPS tracks such as start and end coordinates, total time and top speed and distance. The user document is has user id, first name, last name and so forth.

I want to have aggregate stats for each user that summarizes total distance, total time, total average speed and top speed to date.

I am confused if I should do a map reduce and create an aggregate collection for users, or if I should add these stats to the user document with some kind of cron job type soliuton. I have read many guides about map reduce and aggregation for MongoDB but can't figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your use case for reading the aggregated information .. is this information that changes frequently, or can it be calculated on a schedule?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your aggregate indicator values are per-user, in which case I would simply calculate them and push them directly into the user object as the same time as you update current co-oordinates, speed etc. They would be nice and easy (and fast) to query, and you could aggregate them further if you wished.

When I say pre-calculate, I don't mean MapReduce, which you would use as a batch process, I simply mean calculate on update of the user object.

If your aggregate stats are compiled *across* users, then you could still pre-calculate them on update, but if you also need to be able to query those aggregate stats against some other condition or filter, such as, "tell me what the total distance travelled for all users within x region", then depending on the number of combinations you may not be able to cover all those with pre-calculation.

So, if your aggregate stats ARE across users, AND need some sort of filter applying, then they'll need to be calculated from some snapshot of data. The two approaches here are;

1. the aggregation framework in 2.2
2. MapReduce

You would need to use MapReduce say, if you've a *LOT* of historical data that you want to crunch and you can pre-calculate the results for fast reading later. By my definition, that data isn't changing frequently, but even if it did, you can also use incremental MR to add new results to an existing calculation.

The aggregation framework in 2.2 will allow you to do a lot of this on demand, but it won't be as quick of course as pre-calculated values but way quicker than MR when executed on-demand. It can't cope with the high volume result-sets that you can do with MR, but it's better suited to queries where you don't know the parameter values in advance.

By way of example, if you wanted to calculate the aggregate sums of users stats within a particular lat/long, you couldn't use MR because there are just too many combinations of that filter, so you'd need to do that on the fly.

If however, you wanted it by city, well you could conceivably use MR there because you could stick to a finite set of cities and just pre-calculate them all.

But to wrap up, if your aggregate indicator values are per-user alone, then I'd start by calculating and storing the values inside the user object when I update the user object as I said in the first paragraph. Yes, you're storing the value as well as the inputs, but that's the model that saves you having to calculate on the fly.